# couldn't connect to pyspark yarn resource manager

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, pyspark, hadoop-yarn

The code

```
import pyspark
import numpy as np
import os
import pyspark
import numpy as np
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession, HiveContext
print(str(os.environ['PATH']))
print('java')
print(str(os.environ['JAVA_HOME']))
spark = SparkSession\
.builder \
.appName("PySpark-SQL-Hive-Cron-Month-overview-entry")  \
.config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", "/user/hive/warehouse")\
.config("spark.master", "yarn")  \
.config("spark.cores.max", "2")  \
.config("spark.executor.memory",   "1g")\
.enableHiveSupport() \
.getOrCreate()
SparkContext.setSystemProperty("hive.metastore.uris", "thrift://cmra:9083")
sc =spark.sparkContext
```

Error details hown below
/tmp/hadoop-mrl/nm-local-dir/usercache/mrl/appcache/application_1677651248789_0002/container_1677651248789_0002_02_000001/launch_container.sh: line 55: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'

```
/home/kmrl/.local/bin:
/usr/local/cmra/spark/spark-3.1.2-bin-hadoop3.2/bin:
/usr/local/cmra/spark/spark-3.1.2-bin-hadoop3.2/python:
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:
/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin :/snap/bin:/usr/local/cmra/hadoop/hadoop-3.2.0:
/usr/local/cmra/hadoop/hadoop-3.2.0/bin:
/usr/local/cmra/hadoop/hadoop-3.2.0/bin:
/usr/local/cmra/hadoop/hadoop-3.2.0/sbin:
/usr/local/cmra/hadoop/hadoop-3.2.0/sbin:
/usr/local/cmra/hadoop/hadoop-3.2.0/bin:
/usr/local/cmra/hive/apache-hive-3.1.2-bin/bin
java
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre

------------------

. Failing the application.
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.YarnClientSchedulerBackend.waitForApplication(YarnClientSchedulerBackend.scala:97)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.YarnClientSchedulerBackend.start(YarnClientSchedulerBackend.scala:64)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl.start(TaskSchedulerImpl.scala:220)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:579)
        at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.<init>(JavaSparkContext.scala:58)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:247)
        at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
        at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:238)
        at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.invokeConstructor(ConstructorCommand.java:80)
        at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.execute(ConstructorCommand.java:69)
        at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
23/03/01 06:22:50 WARN YarnSchedulerBackend$YarnSchedulerEndpoint: Attempted to request executors before the AM has registered!
```

Comment: Can you share the code you run?

Comment: @ozlemg now added